# Injecting an existing Jgroups channel into Infinispan configuration

Tags: infinispan, jgroups

My application started to use Jgroups long ago for cluster event synchronization.

Now we are introducing Spring @Cache annotation for distributed caching, and we chose Infinispan as our main cache provider.

I am in the process of learning Infinispan 7.1 configuration, and so far I got that Infinispan is mainly based over Jgroups, in fact it instantiates its own Jchannel based on configuration file.

I have concerns on possible *clashes* and *redundancies* if I allow multiple entities to configure their own Jgroups independently. I.e. my application features an implementation of a distributed status view of the cluster which displays basic hardware data. We had a hard time debugging duplicate and out-of-date nodes.

So, my brief question is: is it possible to tell Infinispan to run over a pre-existing instance (possibly instantiated by an existing Spring bean / singleton object) of Jgroups channel? I currently have a singleton object holding a reference to Jchannel.

My idea is that Infinispan will send messages over existing channel, and plus I will have the ability to implement code to monitor the channel in the future.

Comment: The easiest way to get started with Infinispan and Spring is to use [these starters](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-spring-boot). Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As @Galder Zamarreño we provide Spring Boot Starters as well as a standard Spring Cache extension. You may find a small tutorial [here](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/tree/master/spring) and the documentation [here](http://infinispan.org/docs/dev/user_guide/user_guide.html#using_infinispan_with_spring_boot). For Spring Boot, have also at [this tutorial](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot).